# uitableview re-order won't work, source always equal to destination

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a tableview that won't reorder. It looks like moveRowAtIndexPath is never called with a sourceIndexPath that is different from the destinationIndexPath. When I pull a row, it bounces back to its starting location as if the row didn't support movement.

I tried implementing all the "canMove/canEdit/propose" methods to return YES, but I observe the same behavior. What's going on?

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath
       toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath {

    NSLog(@"%d -> %d", [sourceIndexPath row], [destinationIndexPath row]);
    if ([sourceIndexPath row] == [destinationIndexPath row]) {
        return;
    }

    MyDomain *domain = [self getObject];
    [domain.stuff exchangeObjectAtIndex:(NSUInteger) [sourceIndexPath row] withObjectAtIndex:(NSUInteger) [destinationIndexPath row]];
}
```

Comment: Did you implement `tableView:targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:toProposedIndexPath:`? If so, post it too.

Comment: I did not implement that method.

Comment: OK. Then some silly questions - do you have more than 1 row? Are you dragging the row straight up or down? As you drag the row over another row, the other row should move up or down to the open spot. Is this a plain or grouped table?

Comment: Grouped table, and I have 3 rows. I have tried moving all rows. The other rows do not start moving at all. I will answer any silly questions if it leads to a solution to my problem. :P

Comment: Here's a video of me trying to order: http://screencast.com/t/wxoAoKDsa

Comment: Via unit tests, I've confirmed that if this method gets called with different index paths, the model is updated appropriately. I can't get it to ever give me two numbers, though. It's always 0 -> 0 or 1 -> 1 or 2 -> 2

Comment: Based on the video this isn't a code issue. I actually think you are having issues dragging a row in the simulator. Try this on a real device.

Comment: Note that using exchangeObjectAtIndex:... is probably wrong. You have to remove the object at sourceIndexPath and insert it at destinationIndexPath, that's different from exchanging the objects. - See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/ManageReorderRow/ManageReorderRow.html for sample code from Apple.

Comment: @Martin: That's not the issue. I never receive different indexPaths, so that code isn't hit.

This also fails on the device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using IIViewDeckController, which cancels panning in views.

When setting up the ViewDeckController, do this:
self.panningCancelsTouchesInView = NO;

Comment: Had this exact problem with a sliding view controller and trying to re-sort a table on the root view controller. Thank you!!!