# Can't reorder rows in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have encountered an issue when trying to reorder rows in `UITableView`. 
I have the function `tableView:moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:` triggered, but `fromIndexPath` is equal to `toIndexPath` (i.e. source == destination). 
I saw the same issue here: [uitableview re-order won't work, source always equal to destination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16628615/uitableview-re-order-wont-work-source-always-equal-to-destination)
But the solution was - to use different library. That is not a variant for me.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath {
    //fromIndexPath is equal to toIndexPath, so nothing is exchaned
    [self.table_data exchangeObjectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row withObjectAtIndex:toIndexPath.row];
}
```

My table is in editable mode, I have  `canMoveRowAtIndexPath:` returning `YES`. My it does not help. 
How come? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is there any change in the path values depending on relative positions of the rows or are the **always** equal?

Comment: they are always equal
It does not matter which row in what direction I would drag

Comment: FYI - you can't use `exchangeObjectAtIndex:withObjectAtIndex:` to move an object. That method swaps the two objects. Not at all what you want.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem was in custom pan gesture recognizer.
It somehow was in conflict with rows drag-drop behavior

Setting `myGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;` fixed the issue

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It works.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    arr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"First",@"Second",@"Third",@"Fourth", nil];    
    self.tableView.editing = YES;
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return arr.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:100];
    [label setText:[arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath
{
    NSString *stringToMove = arr[sourceIndexPath.row];
    [arr removeObjectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row];
    [arr insertObject:stringToMove atIndex:destinationIndexPath.row];
}
```

Check the screenshot -

[image]

[image]

Comment: yep, it works. It works on a new project, but it does not work in my project. I dunno what is the reason of such behavior

Comment: the problem was in custom gesture recognizer
it somehow was in conflict with rows drag function